# Doubt regarding use of quantifier:

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I feel this is an important question for me to understand to get the whole hang of it.

> Everyone except one student in your class has an internet connection

Given I(x) = x has an internet connection, domain: set of all students in my class.

My solution is:

∀x ∃y {(x ≠ y)⟶I(x) ⋀ ㄱI(y) ⋀ ∀k(ㄱI(k)⟶(y=k))}


Thought pattern:

For every student x,there is a student y for which if x is not y, then x has internet connection. The y guy(s) doesn't have internet connection, and to make y unique, add the later stuff ...⋀ ∀k(ㄱI(k)⟶(y=k))

Comment: You should have $\exists y$ first, because the student that doesn't have internet is fixed and doesn't depend on what student $x$ we're checking.

Comment: The doubt is how to make that y unique. Exactly one student NOT having internet connection. Did I do it right there?

Comment: @Arthur yeah, you are right. This will be read as 'for every student x, there is a y' which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression doesn't tell us anything. Note that any formula that reads "$\forall x\exists y((x\neq y)\to\cdots)$" is necessarily true because $y=x$ is a $y$ that exists and makes the contents of the parenthesis true.

Rather, I would think like this: There is a student that does not have internet, and every other student has internet. It would read like this:
$$
\exists y(\lnot I(y)\land\forall x(x\neq y\to I(x)))
$$

Comment: But I need EXACTLY ONE student not having internet!

Comment: Or can I simply give ∃!y (¬I(y))? hehe

Comment: No, this makes it exactly one, because $\forall x(x\neq y \to I(x))$ says that every other student has internet.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.